# MYSQL query fails with encoded entities

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which should count how many rows there are with the same values:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM top2000 where artist='$arEnt' AND title='$tiEnt'", $link);
```

It's works perfectly, but since users can typ in '"', "'" or any other non alphabetic charactar, I first encode their values using:

```
$entry = htmlentities($tEcho, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
list($arEnt, $tiEnt) = split(' - ', $entry);
```

Don't get me wrong, this works out fine until somebody uses a quote or something for example:

```
SELECT * FROM top2000 where artist='DJ Stephanie' AND title='Karma&#039;s A Bitch'
```

The values in the database are the following:

```
title='DJ Stephanie' 
artist = 'Karma&#039;s A Bitch'
```

Exactly the same as you can see but mysql_num_rows returns 0. Why?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: As Jason McCreary said, you must move on, and stop using mysql_ functions. Using it will expose your site to sql-injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: What is your table encoding?

Comment: @Shamil utf8_general_ci

Comment: If you were to use mysqli/PDO with parametrized prepared statements, you would save yourself all this encoding hassle.

Comment: I'll get in to mysqli but for now I have to fix this somehow. But I'm cluesless at this point

Comment: Create/change your table collation = `utf-8`, set names to `utf-8`. Not `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @Shamil Just changed it to UTF-8 but it doesn't seem to solve anything

Comment: @BartScheffer that was more of a first step, is there a reason why you're storing strings with entities in the database?

Comment: @Shamil Ah Ok. Reason is that people can vote on songs by filling in their favorites. Script compares their input with the database to ensure users fill in a Hardstyle related song. But those song & artist names can have quotes and sup's

Comment: @BartScheffer `mysql_real_escape_string` and storing the values.. it would have been much cleaner.

Comment: @Shamil I was actually thinking about that too but with 7000 rows in that database with encoded titles & artists it's way too late for that

Comment: @Shamil It's never too late for that - that's what upgrade scripts are for.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)